# MySQL growth 500k records/day

Tags: mysql, scalability

Im not a DBA however am an infrastructure guy used to installing and configuring database servers such as MSSQL, MySQL, MongoDB etc...

I have a MySQL database which is being used for archival of building systems data. Once a night, the building management system will archive its data which results in around 500k rows of data being added across various tables in the database.

There are 12,000 tables in this database and overall it contains 7 billion records.

Are there any issues with growth? The database is currently 150GB and this is a purely write only load. There will hardly ever be any read activity on this DB.

I understand IOPS and performance scaling, this is a question about MySQL itself and specifically its ability dealing with a DB of this size.

Is there anything I should be aware of?

EDIT: I am fully aware that this is not ideal, hence this post but I am totally 100% unable to change the way the third party stores its info in the DB so don't have much of a choice but ask how I can best 'optimise' SQL to work with what its given.

Thanks

Comment: The number of tables is a give away that you are doing something wrong. Look into the design

Answer (score 3):

MySQL can handle it, but not without some care.

12,000 tables is a red flag.  Each table is one (or more) OS file.  This large a number, especially if in a single database, can cause sluggishness.

Are the records merely written to the tables?  Or are they used to "update" existing rows?

I would load the 500K rows into a table(s), cleanup the data, then copy it into the real tables.

Generally, I would do the work 1000 rows at a time.  But this might vary depending on whether you have Replication, which Engine you are using, etc.

7B in 150GB smells like MyISAM; is it?

If you are "never" reading it, why put it in a database?  Why not in flat files?

What does the incoming data look like?  CSV?  mysqldump?  Other?

Simple-minded code should be able to load a nightly dump in an hour or two.  More advanced coding might get it down to less than an hour.

Comment: I am unable to change the design since the data is coming directly from a 3rd party app using the oracle mysql connector. Each 'data point' is written into its own table which will be appended to every day with more rows. So if the point data is half hourly readings then every day, each table will receive 48 new rows.

Storage engine is InnoDB, i should have mentioned that my 150GB figure was a guess based on some quick maths. It has only done the initial 200 tables by the time i left site.

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS;` gives you the `Data_length` and `Index_length` for each table in a database.  A more complex formula against `information_schema` would give you all the info, and do the the sum.

Comment: If you are computing table size from column size, multiple the answer by 2 or 3 to get a closer estimate for InnoDB size.  (There is a lot of overhead.)

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Rick and Ed, 12,000 tables is too much and if you can opt for a more optimal database design, you'll be better off in the long run.

If you can't change the database design though, you could spread the existing tables over several volumes using the Innodb Engine, [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) and the [file_per_table tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html) available with [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)  in MySQL 5.6.

[Choosing the location of your MySQL Files](http://[https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/choose_the_location_of_your][3])

> Allows you to choose the location of specific tables.  For example,
>   you can place critical tables onto an SSD drive while leaving the
>   system tablespace on a hard drive.  Conversely, you can store you
>   primary database files on an SSD and put a seldom used but very large
>   archive or reference table on a larger cheaper hard drive.

From MySQL's documentation : [14.4.5 Creating a File-Per-Table Tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html)

```
mysql> USE test;
Database changed

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| innodb_file_per_table | ON    |
+-----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/alternative/directory';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

# MySQL creates a .ibd file for the new table in a subdirectory that corresponding  
# to the database name

db_user@ubuntu:~/alternative/directory/test$ ls
t1.ibd

# MySQL creates a .isl file containing the path name for the table in a directory 
# beneath the MySQL data directory

db_user@ubuntu:~/mysql/data/test$ ls
db.opt  t1.frm  t1.isl
```

At the very least, you could migrate your larger tables to this new design

**Very simplifed migration process**

Assuming you have another empty volume to store MySQL's tables already setup.

1. Backup the tables you want to migrate to another volume
2. Modify the dump file so that the CREATE TABLE uses the
   alternative/directory.
3. Restore your data.

If Rick is right and you are using MyISAM, then the process would also have to include modifying the table engine in the dump file for each table you want to migrate.

Comment: Raid striping is more efficient than manually picking what device to put tables on.  And, if there is no parallelism, `DATA DIRECTORY` provides no speed.

Comment: For _small_ _InnoDB_ tables, it is better to turn off file_per_table and let them be in ibdata1.  That avoids 12,000 .ibd files (but not the 12,000 .frm files).

Comment: @RickJames what are the implications of doing this?

Comment: Fewer _files_ --> slightly better performance.  Depending on how big the tables are, there may or may not be a change on overall disk space usage.  OTOH, if you later decide to combine lots of tables into a few, having them in ibdata1 will make it difficult to recoup disk space.  (ibdata1 never shrinks.)